# an expression for the $ e^x $ using the binomial theorem

Tags: exponential-function

Is it possible using the Binomial theorem , to prove the identity

$$ e \sim \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^\frac{1}{n}\sim \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!} $$

where $ n \to \infty $

Comment: There is no $x$ in the middle expression, there should be one.

Comment: No, the binomial theorem would require $(1+1/n)$ to be raised to an integer power.

Comment: @Abdallah Hammam: You've changed the question, the OP wanted to know whether you could find $e^x$ using the binomial theorem, not merely $e$.

Comment: How do you define $e$ without one of these limits?

Comment: @Mathematician42 It was not correct.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam  I up-voted because there's an extended version of the binomial theorem (in most calc books) which would handle the fractional exponent.  It probably doesn't matter whether there's an $x$ involved or not; the answer will come out the same.

Comment: @JoseGarcia You probably wanted $(1+1/n)^n$, not (1+1/n)^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\pars{1 + {1 \over n}}^{n}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
\pars{1 \over n}^{k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k!}
\,{n! \over \pars{n - k}!n^{k}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\hspace{3mm}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k!}
\,{\root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\,\,\expo{-n} \over
\bracks{\root{2\pi}
\pars{n - k}^{n - k + 1/2}\,\,\,
\expo{-\pars{n - k}}\,}n^{k}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k!}\,{\expo{-k} \over
\bracks{n^{-k}\,\,\pars{1 - k/n}^{n}\,\,
\pars{1 - k/n}^{1/2 - k}\,\,}n^{k}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim} & \hspace{5mm}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{1 \over k!}\,{\expo{-k} \over
\bracks{n^{-k}\ \times\ \expo{-k}\ \times\ 1}
n^{k}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\to} & \hspace{5mm}
\bbox[#ffe,15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\color{#44f}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\,\,{1 \over k!}}}} \\ &
\end{align}